Reducing required length of a mass driver using loop?
If you had a loop of electromagnets with an encapsulated payload inside vacuum tubes, how fast could you accelerate the capsule to before it reached some maximum velocity?
What effect would scale have on the answer to that hypothetical?
And would it be worthwhile to have such a loop as a first stage in a mass driver to reduce material and space requirements?

Well, getting things to go around the loop is a whole other engineering problem...

SpinLaunch FTW.

"electromagnets ... vacuum ... how fast?"
I guess light speed. More on physics.SE. But asking here provides the practical answers I think You expected.

You can certainly do this, but the maximum potential speed and other technical questions depend heavily on the desired operating parameters of the accelerator. There isn't a simple answer.
While in the loop track, you need a way to provide enough centripetal force to stop the cargo from punching out through the wall of the loop. That could be provided by magnets, or by wheels on a physical track, or whatever -- but also remember that whatever force the loop puts on the cargo, the loop has to withstand an equal and opposite force. The loop forces the cargo onto a curved path, and in return the cargo puts potentially enormous forces on the loop. The physical engineering of the loop determines what the maximums are for that -- the wider the loop, the lower the forces, but you gain less benefit as compared to a straight track.
That curve will also produce equivalent G-loading on the cargo based on the radius of the loop. If you're building a mass driver weapon or delivering the output from a mining/smelting operation, maybe that doesn't matter, because you're firing a solid metal slug and the limiting factor is purely the mechanical forces you're putting on the loop itself.  But if you're trying to use a mass driver to launch goods or living humans, you probably need to keep it down to a single digit number of Gs to prevent damaging your products or injuring your passengers.
As an example of this that uses a physical rotor instead of magnets, look at the SpinLaunch project. The technical limitations of the system are non-trivial -- it's not remotely suitable for anything living, and even electronics have to be designed to withstand the forces involved, but I could certainly see a similar system that's intended to operate in a hard vacuum environment and adds a magnetic track to the outbound end of the thing.

I figured being in the tube & using em would reduce friction & heat. and being in a sturdy capsule with gel padding internally would protect cargo. I think if the system had to go slow enough to support bio cargo it wouldn't be worthwhile. But even if it was just able to launch raw materials to be collected and used for construction in space that would still be useful, even if you couldn't deliver anything else. Ideally you could deliver anything that wasn't overly fragile, if the forces were consistent & stable things wont shake loose etc, especially if firmly embedded in the casing?

Padding is typically not an issue; when we talk about force loading limits, we're not talking about objects flying around inside the capsule, we're just talking about things breaking due to their own weight.

Like on material molecular structures level? Or, if you have a gameboy as a unit internal components will break off?

Meaning internal and external components can bend or break from the stresses. If you put  satellite into a launch system that subjects it to 50 G forces, all sorts of antennas, solar arrays, batteries, even circuit boards and wiring, can become too heavy for their mountings to support, or just bend under the force and become damaged.  You can design around that, but it's a significant limitation on the kinds of things you can launch.

Understood. I think the main use would be in getting material to construct fab facilities in space, then it would be significantly easier to expand space infrastructure and build things directly in space.

Centripetal acceleration, $a_c$ is
$$a_c={v^2 \over r}$$
If 'r' is the radius of the planet, and 'v' is orbital velocity, then '$a_c$' will be 1G. If you travel in a circle with a radius of $0.5 \times r$ but maintain 'v' you'll end up with 2 G's of acceleration. If your payload and passengers can withstand 10 Gs, then the circle's radius will be $r_{planet} \over 10$, or 637.8 km and it's circumference will be ~4000km.
At 10 G's, you can accelerate in a straight line up to orbital velocity in a lot less distance than 4000km.
$$t={v \over a} = {7800 \over {10 \times 9.8}} ~= 80sec$$
$$d = 0.5at^2 = (0.5)(10 \times 9.8)*(80^2) = 310408m ~= 310 km$$
So, it makes more sense to accelerate in a straight line if your goal is orbital speeds and you want to keep the g-forces in the "human-rated" range.

I don't really want to keep the g-forces in survivable ranges, just to reduce construction requirements of the overall system by reaching some maximum in a loop. I'll think over the maths provided.

If you don't care about G-forces, just accelerate hard in a straight line @FellahWithNoMentalModelsHere

@JCRM If we aren't worried about keeping the g-forces under control, then I think we can assume the track is already accelerating at maximum capacity and we're now looking for ways to reduce the accelerator footprint by having the cargo reuse part of the track. That's why particle accelerators are in a ring and not just a line that pushes harder.

@DarthPseudonym That bit about particle colliders is not really true. There are linear accelerators and colliders. The reason for circular colliders is not to reuse the accelerator, but to reuse the particles - most of them pass each other without colliding and would be a huge waste of energy. Linear colliders could also do this but it is much more complicated. For a mass driver, the consideration is if can you apply more force to revolve a mass around the track than you can push forwards with. That may be true e.g. if power cannot be delivered fast enough to accelerate straight.

@Morphit The LHC takes almost half an hour to get the particle stream up to the desired operational speed. Even the old SPS that now serves as the "preaccelerator" for LHC takes a few seconds to get to its maximum energy, which represents thousands of laps around the 7 km track.

How do you build a 4000km straight line?  You have to curve your launcher when you're at that scale.

an ion drive accelerates particals to "fast enough" speeds in cms; rail guns in meters.
Particle accelerators are big because the particles are going fast, and the distance gives time.
If you're using a circular track you'll be spending more energy accelerating centripetally than linearly
